# can Entity map to one extra coulmn in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a class mapped with DB with 8 column but in hql i am creating 9th column in select statement , with case when statement. it is giving unexpected toekn, seems to be syntax error. But I am not able to figure out the exact syntax error.

Exception I got

org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 353

[select un.id, un.timestamp, un.recipientUser, un.sendingUser,un.messageType, un.body, un.title, un.readTimestamp, case when sendingUser > recipientUser then CONCAT(sendingUser,'-',recipientUser) ELSE CONCAT(recipientUser,'-',sendingUser) END as normalised_message_parties from com.xxxxx.platform.xxx.notification.xxxxxx.UserNotification un 
inner join  ( select max(timestamp) as timestamp, case when sendingUser > recipientUser then CONCAT(sendingUser,'-',recipientUser) ELSE CONCAT(recipientUser,'-',sendingUser) END as normalised_message_parties   from com.xxxxx.platform.xxx.notification.xxxxxx.UserNotification un where un.sendingUser like :userID or un.recipientUser like :userID  group by normalised_message_parties)  as m on ( m.normalised_message_parties = normalised_message_parties and m.timestamp = un.timestamp) order by timestamp DESC]

cant find out the problem.. 
I dont what else you required to help me.. so do let me know i will post it.. 
but as far i think.. problem relay in query syntax. 
i am using hibernate 3.4

Answer (score 0):

The column is not the problem. You cannot use a subselect in the FROM clause. The Hibernate documentation states, that this is only possible in the SELECT or WHERE clause. You'll need to

- rewrite your query or
- provide a view

See the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries) for more detailed information.

Comment: Actually problem was some where else. Dont know why this message was shown.  These two   "un.body, un.title" are LONGTEXT field, not supporting with my current hibernate version. I still confuse why "unexpected token" was showing as error.. same query is woking fine now..

Comment: So did you update your hibernate version? What was the solution?

Comment: i wrote custom mysql dialect for handling long text. after this error goes out.. :)